# how to reset remote branch to old commit

Tags: git

I have a remote branch which has too many commits. I would like to remove all commits after 37fba70e from it. Here is what it looks like on bitbucket:

[image]

I did `git branch -f origin/start-defblock-on-long-hyphen 37fba70e` locally and now my log looks like:

```
commit 37fba70ef7db1ce244d6e0c0d4e3b42d95dd7cb0 (HEAD -> origin/start-defblock-on-long-hyphen)
Author: First Last <first.last@company.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 11 13:28:51 2019 +0200

    added ')].' to valid end

commit 30fa3879845184405aba590b85380a6793ed5051
Author: First Last <first.last@company.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 10 16:02:31 2019 +0200

    accept to start def on moment start if start element is long dash

commit 57157406ab149b2934bfb2db7e6a6021bf950e02
Author: First Last <first.last@company.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 10 15:42:06 2019 +0200

    added long dash to valid start
```

This looks correct, so I want to push these changes to bitbucket, but `git push origin start-defblock-on-long-hyphen` does not change anything. The output is simply:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

and the Bitbucket commit history looks the same as before.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: do you just want to remove commits or commit changes.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran:

> ```
> git branch -f origin/start-defblock-on-long-hyphen 37fba70e
> ```

This was a mistake!  This created a *local* branch named `origin/start-defblock-on-long-hyphen`.  This situation is quite confusing (to everyone) because normally names starting with `origin/` are reserved for your own remote-tracking names.

Your `git log` output now begins with:

```
commit 37fba70ef7db1ce244d6e0c0d4e3b42d95dd7cb0 (HEAD -> origin/start-defblock-on-long-hyphen)
```

This means you also ran `git checkout origin/start-defblock-on-long-hyphen`, and it is now your current branch.

To fix this, you should probably first *rename* this local branch to a more local-looking name:

```
git branch -m origin/start-defblock-on-long-hyphen start-defblock-on-long-hyphen
```

I expect that this will fail, because I believe you *also* have a *local* branch named `start-defblock-on-long-hyphen`.  If so, you can:

- rename that branch, then rename this one;
- delete that branch, then rename this one; or
- check out that branch, force it to the desired commit, and delete the `origin/` local name entirely.

The exact choice of which of these actions to take is up to you—each is slightly, subtly different, but in the end they'll probably all end up having the same effect.  The *safest* is to rename the local one first, then the `origin/`-named local one:

```
git branch -m start-defblock-on-long-hyphen old-start-defblock-on-long-hyphen
git branch -m origin/start-defblock-on-long-hyphen start-defblock-on-long-hyphen
```

(note that if you already have a local branch named `start-defblock-on-long-hyphen`, you have a separate problem).  Once you have done that, you can repeat your:

> ```
> git push origin start-defblock-on-long-hyphen
> ```

which should immediately fail because you'll have to use `--force` or equivalent to command the Git on the receiving end of this operation—i.e., the Git over on Bitbucket—to lose all the extra commits, but if that's the goal, and any other users of this Bitbucket Git agree that it's OK to lose them, go ahead and use `--force`.  You may also want to use the `-u` or `--set-upstream` flag during the push, i.e.:

```
git push --force -u origin start-defblock-on-long-hyphen
```

Comment: This will erase the history and could confuse other developers if they're branched off those commits. You could also `git revert` the commits to end in a null set.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon: right, hence the "if" and "and" in "if that's the goal, and other users are OK with this"...

Comment: My bad. Just skimmed your post. Where is the tldr; ;) Lots of good info